# Launching an AlertDialog from a subclassed SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, simplecursoradapter, onclicklistener

I have subclassed SimpleCursorAdapter in order to create a custom list entry layout containing a Button. I can get as far as making the button write to the log. My intent is to launch an AlertDialog, but I have yet to find a way to get a FragmentManager to launch the DialogFragment. I'm using the fragment compatibility components.

For this case I realize there may be simpler solutions which avoid the use of a SimpleCursorAdapter, but I am trying to learn this case before I work on more complicated components.

Here is the adapter:

```
public class ActiveProfileAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "ActiveProfileAdapter";
    private final Cursor dataCursor;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ActiveProfileAdapter(final Context context, final int layout, final Cursor dataCursor, final String[] from,
            final int[] to, final int flags) {
        super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to, flags);
        this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.profilebar_list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.currentprofile);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        final int label_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ProfilesColumns.USERNAME);
        if (label_index == -1) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Bad column name");
        }

        final String label = dataCursor.getString(label_index);
        holder.button1.setText(label);
        holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Launch AlertDialog Fragment when this button is pressed");
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        Button button1;
    }
}
```

Here is the fragment which calls the adapter:

```
public class ActiveProfileFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final int LIST_LOADER = R.loader.browsefragloader;
    protected int layout = R.layout.profilebar_fragment;
    protected SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter;

    protected final Uri table = ProfileProvider.URI_ACTIVEPROFILEVIEW;
    protected String[] uiBindFrom = { ProfilesColumns.USERNAME };
    protected String[] createProjection = { CommonDatabaseHelper._ID, ProfilesColumns.USERNAME };
    protected int[] uiBindTo = { R.id.currentprofile };

    // layout for list item
    protected int entryLayout = R.layout.profilebar_list_item;

    Button openProfile;

    public ActiveProfileFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(table, createProjection, null, null, null);
        listAdapter = new ActiveProfileAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), entryLayout, c, uiBindFrom,
                uiBindTo, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LIST_LOADER, null, this);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(final int id, final Bundle args) {
        final String[] projection = createProjection;
        final CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), table, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(final Loader<Cursor> loader, final Cursor cursor) {
        listAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(final Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        listAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

And here is the activity which contains the fragment:

```
public class BrowseActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    protected int layout = R.layout.browse_viewer;

    final Fragment profileBarFragment = new ActiveProfileFragment();
    final Fragment fragment0 = new BrowseFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout);
        final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.profilebarfragment, profileBarFragment);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment0);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

**Resolved**
I hit upon a very simple solution. I moved the adapter into the fragment activity so that I could reference the fragment's components locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the adapter inside the fragment so that it has access to the activity's resources.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple, just create your dialog fragment class, call it in your button `onClick` method and then use the `show` method with `getFragmentManager()` and the "dialog" keyword...

```
YourDialogFragment dialogFragment = new YourDialogFragment();
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Comment: How do I call getFragmentManager from within the CursorAdapter?

Comment: Alternately, how do I get a click in a custom list entry layout to respond from an activity so that I can call getFragmentManager.

Comment: I declare the listener inliine in the adapter's getView. It doesn't have access to getFragmentManager since it is inside the adapter. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't reading closely enough.  I thought you had a button *outside* of the listview.  I know I've done a dialog from a button *in* a listview before, just can't recall how... I'll search through my projects.